# Null RecyclerView when calling it from another RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that is displaying my CardView correctly. That CardView also contains a RecyclerView and I am trying to get that to show with hard coded data. The problem is I am getting null on the .setHasFixedSize(true) or any line after the second RecyclerView is declared.

I am calling the second RecyclerView after the first one is created...I think.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView mWeatherTemp, mWeatherDescript;
    Context context;
    private ArrayList days;
    private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mMainToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.weather_cool));

        mWeatherTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWeatherTemp);
        mWeatherDescript = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWeatherText);

        Typeface robotDisplay3 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "font/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        mWeatherTemp.setTypeface(robotDisplay3);
        initCardView();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public void initCardView() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mMainRV);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        days = new ArrayList();
        days.add("TODAY");
        days.add("TOMORROW");
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new HomeRecyclerAdapter(days);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        initHourlyGrid();
    }

    public void initHourlyGrid() {
        List<HourlyForcast> listItem = getAllItemList();
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 4);
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.hourlyRecycler);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); //getting error here but happens if I comment this out, I am calling this method after the first RecyclerView method is called. So not sure whats going on. 
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter = new HourlyForcastAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listItem);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private List<HourlyForcast> getAllItemList() {
        List<HourlyForcast> allHours = new ArrayList<>();
        allHours.add(new HourlyForcast("4:00 PM", "8°", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        allHours.add(new HourlyForcast("5:00 PM", "6°", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        allHours.add(new HourlyForcast("6:00 PM", "5°", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        allHours.add(new HourlyForcast("7:00 PM", "3°", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        allHours.add(new HourlyForcast("8:00 PM", "3°", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        allHours.add(new HourlyForcast("9:00 PM", "3°", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        allHours.add(new HourlyForcast("10:00 PM", "4°", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        allHours.add(new HourlyForcast("11:00 PM", "60°", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

        return allHours;
    }
}

public class HourlyForcastAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HourlyForcastAdapter.HourlyViewHolder> {
    private List<HourlyForcast> itemList;
    private Context context;

    public HourlyForcastAdapter(Context context, List<HourlyForcast> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public HourlyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hourly_single, parent, false);
        return new HourlyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HourlyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTimeText.setText(itemList.get(position).getTime());
        holder.mDegreeText.setText(itemList.get(position).getDegrees());
        holder.mWeatherIcon.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getImageID());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    public static class HourlyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mTimeText, mDegreeText;
        ImageView mWeatherIcon;

        public HourlyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTimeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timePlaceHolder);
            mDegreeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.degreePlaceHolder);
            mWeatherIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.weatherIconHolder);
        }
    }
}


public class HomeRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> dates;
    Context context;

    public HomeRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> dates) {
        this.dates = dates;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hourly_cardview, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Typeface titleStyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "font/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
        holder.mDate.setTypeface(titleStyle);
        holder.mDate.setText(dates.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dates.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mDate;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use findViewById to get the View in the adapter of the outer RecyclerView. To init the sub RecyclerView in the HomeRecyclerAdapter can solve this problem.

like this

```

```
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 4);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                           .inflate(R.layout. hourlyRecycler, parent, false);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); 
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new HourlyForcastAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listItem);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);      

    // or move above code into ViewHolder
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}
```

```

Comment: How would I go about calling the second RecyclerView from the first one's adapter? Would I do that onCreatViewHolder(if so how do I call another layout to inflate)?

Comment: So I did the same thing but placed it inside the onBindViewHolder. Is there any difference? Yours worked for me but so did what I did in onBindViewHolder. Is one better then the other and if so why? Or does it not matter?

Comment: onCreateViewHolder  is only called once when the ViewHolder first created, so inflater layout or new some instance here;  onBindViewHolder is called every time this viewholder should be update, so setText or setImage to update this ViewHolder here.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

the logic slightly rigid, in your main adapter ,initialize the hourly recycler view in constructor just like any other view.Then create your external adapter, in onBindviewHolder use the position for current cardview access the recyclerview then set the adapter.

Comment: Where in the first RecyclerView or Second? The second one I need a grid view for how I want the data to be displayed.

Comment: try the first. I think i might know the problem

Comment: I did  //RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false); and got the same results, null for the second recyclerview

Comment: question here: RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.hourlyRecycler);

Comment: is that layout in the main layout?R.layout.activity_main

Comment: no its in the layout that the first RecyclerView is generating

Comment: then that is your problem.

Comment: that layout is not in your main. can't find. use the adapter

Comment: How would I go about calling the second recycler in the first ones adapter? Now I am really getting confused. How do I call a adapter within an adapter?

Answer (score 0):

You must call findViewById for the sub Recycle view inside the adapter and put it in the View holder